# Get/select the axis spacing/interval on base plot

Tags: r, plot, axis, intervals, spacing

I would like to grab the axis spacing/interval that is being used in the base `plot`.

I would like to use this to manual add to `xlim=` or `ylim=`.

How could you find this out? Seems like everyone is interested in set/changing the axis spacing/intervals but not grabbing/selecting the automatically set one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at `?par` you can use `xaxp` or `yaxp` to find the intervals of the tick marks as well as the number of tick marks. To find the exact interval size/length of axis, you can do some arithmetic:

for example, for yaxis tick intervals you can do:

`(abs(par()$yaxp[1]) + par()$yaxp[2]) / par()$yaxp[3]`

Answer (score 1):

You may check `par()$usr` after a `plot`.

```
plot(1:10, (1:10 + 20))  ## example
par()$usr
# [1]  0.64 10.36 20.64 30.36
```

From `?par`

> `usr`: A vector of the form c(x1, x2, y1, y2) giving the extremes of
>   the user coordinates of the plotting region. When a logarithmic scale
>   is in use (i.e., par("xlog") is true, see below), then the x-limits
>   will be 10 ^ par("usr")[1:2]. Similarly for the y-axis.

Comment: hmm not the direct answer I was looking for, but the par() helped me in finding the solution, thanks